# div or span that dynamically/continually changes width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the example code from [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
and I would like to make the div expand automatically based on a counter, based on the time, as the counter or time changes the div gets wider. I can't figure out how to use a variable to replace the width: "70%"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
<style type="text/css">
div {
background-color:#bca;width:100px;border:1px solid green;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="go">» Run</button>
    <div id="block">
      Hello!
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Using multiple unit types within one animation. */
 $("#go").click(function(){  $("#block").animate({    width: "70%",    opacity: 0.4,    marginLeft: "0.6in",    fontSize: "3em",    borderWidth: "10px"  }, 1500 );});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you are off to a good start. Do you have any research or other code of what you have tried to move towards the solution you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Please sample code to use a variable for width:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
<style type="text/css">
div {
background-color:#bca;width:100px;border:1px solid green;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="go">» Run</button>
    <div id="block">
      Hello!
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var someWidth = "70%";
/* Using multiple unit types within one animation. */
 $("#go").click(function(){  $("#block").animate({    width: someWidth,    opacity: 0.4,    marginLeft: "0.6in",    fontSize: "3em",    borderWidth: "10px"  }, 1500 );});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I came up with the code posted at the link below. The animate part works fine but it doesn't work at the link because it's not pulling the external javascripts. When you click on the boxes, you can set the background color for the box. My question is, how can I store the users color selections so that they are automatically used the next time the user opens this web page. The page will be opened from a local hard drive, not from a web server.  I need the cookie or local storage to work with Chrome and IE8 [link]http://jsfiddle.net/3m4uF/[link]

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative animation by specifying `+=` as follows

```
$("#go").click(function(){  
         $("#block").animate({   
                             width: "+=5%",   
                             opacity: 0.4,
                             marginLeft: "0.6in",  
                             fontSize: "3em",   
                             borderWidth: "10px"  
                            }, 1500 );
         });
```

This will expand div by `5%` every time function is called.Adjust it fit your need.
Rather if you would like to `animate` on interval basis call this function in `setInterval`.This will call `animate` every 2000 milliseconds.

```
setInterval( function(){

        $("#block").animate({   
                             width: "+=5%",   
                             opacity: 0.4,
                             marginLeft: "0.6in",  
                             fontSize: "3em",   
                             borderWidth: "10px"  

                    }, 1500 );               

             },2000);
```